# Reading and Verifying Certificates

Tags: c++, openssl, certificate, x509certificate, x509

Hi I have two certificates, i.e mycert.crt and root.crt. and I need to verfiy if my certificate is signed by root certificate. 
I am using the following code to do so using the following code but I am getting an error 
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

```
static int verifyCerti (BYTE *cert1, BYTE *cert2, int certlenght1, int certlenght2);

int main (int ac, char **av)
{
    FILE     *f_in, *f_in2;
    BYTE     *certBuf, *certBuf2;
    UINT32   certBufLen,certBufLen2;
    UINT32   certLen,certLen2;
    int      result;


    //////////// Reading first certificate/////

    certBufLen = 0;
    certBuf = malloc (1);
    //for (i=0; i<nCerts; i++) {
    if ((f_in = fopen (av[1], "rb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open file %s for input\n", av[1]);
        exit (1);
    }
    fseek (f_in, 0, SEEK_END);
    certLen = ftell (f_in);
    fseek (f_in, 0, SEEK_SET);
    certBuf = realloc (certBuf, certBufLen + certLen);

    if (fread (certBuf+certBufLen, 1, certLen, f_in) != certLen) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to read file %s\n", av[1]);
        exit (1);
    }
    if (certBuf[certBufLen] != 0x30) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Certificate file %s not in binary format\n", av[1]);
        exit (1);
    }
    fclose (f_in);
    printf ("we reach here %s \n", av[1]);


    ////////////////Reading second certificate/////////////////////////////////////////////////


    certBufLen2 = 0;
    certBuf2 = malloc (1);
    if ((f_in2 = fopen (av[2], "rb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open file %s for input\n", av[2]);
        exit (1);
    }
    fseek (f_in2, 0, SEEK_END);
    certLen2 = ftell (f_in2);
    fseek (f_in2, 0, SEEK_SET);
    certBuf2 = realloc (certBuf2, certBufLen2 + certLen2);

    if (fread (certBuf2+certBufLen2, 1, certLen2, f_in2) != certLen2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to read file %s\n", av[2]);
        exit (1);
    }
    if (certBuf2[certBufLen2] != 0x30) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Certificate file %s not in binary format\n", av[2]);
        exit (1);
    }
    fclose (f_in2);

    printf ("we reach here %s \n", av[2]);

    if (verifyCerti (certBuf, certBuf2, certBufLen, certBufLen2) < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Certificate chain is incorrect\n");
        exit (1);
    }
}

static int verifyCerti (BYTE *cert1, BYTE *cert2, int certLen1, int certLen2)
{

    X509 *root;
    X509 *mycert;

    root = d2i_X509 (NULL, (unsigned char const **)&cert2, certLen2);
    mycert = d2i_X509 (NULL, (unsigned char const **)&cert1, certLen1);

    //Get root certificate into root
    //Get mycert into mycert.

    //Get the public key.

    EVP_PKEY *pubkey = X509_get_pubkey(root);


    //verify. result less than or 0 means not verified or some error.

    int result = X509_verify(mycert, pubkey);

    //free the public key.

    EVP_PKEY_free(pubkey);

    return result;    
}
```

The error is i think because of X509_verify(), but I am not sure.

Comment: Did you bother running this under a debugger? And is there any particular reason you're not using `X509 *d2i_X509_fp(FILE *fp, X509 **x)` for your file loads?

Comment: Have you checked the value of root and mycert before passing to X509_verify? They should be a valid certificate.

Comment: For d2i functions, the format of the certificate should be DER. See if the format of the certificate files is DER. If it is other than this, then convert it to DER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the function is to verify if the pkey (public key) verifies with the serverCert signed with a corresponding private key..

What you should actually be passing as the second parameter is the public key, whose corresponding private key had signed the certificate passed in parameter1. I don't think you are passing the correct public key.

Try to get the error codes for the failure using.

```
unsigned int errCode = ERR_get_error();

printf("\nError: %s\n", ERR_error_string(errCode, NULL));
printf("\nLib: %s\n", ERR_lib_error_string(errCode));
printf("\nFunc: %s\n", ERR_func_error_string(errCode));
printf("\nReason: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(errCode));
```

Comment: Yes, that's right.  X509_verify() is used to verify a certificate's own consistency.  I.e. does the signature on the certificate data match the certificate's own public key.  The OP wants to validate the certificate's chain which requires other functions.