# How can I read certificate to verify signature with openssl?

Tags: c++, linux, ssl, openssl

I have generated a private key and corresponding certificate with **openssl** on linux, with these commands:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -out certificate.pem -days 730 -nodes
```

This has generated to me two files: **key.pem** and **certificate.pem**

Using key.pem, with C++ (**PEM_read_PrivateKey**, **RSA_sign**) I have signed some data.

Now using the certificate I want to verify the signature.

However, while reading the certificate, I got an error, ie, the function PEM_read_PUBKEY returns me **NULL**:

```
FILE * certificate_fd = NULL;

std::string cert_file = "certificate.pem";
certificate_fd = fopen(cert_file.toLatin1().data(), "rt");

if (NULL == certificate_fd) return;

EVP_PKEY * certificate = NULL;
certificate = PEM_read_PUBKEY(certificate_fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

What do I do wrong with **PEM_read_PUBKEY**?

The content of certificate.pem is this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Edit:**

I have seen that the problem is with **-------BEGIN CERTIFICATE------** / **------END CERTIFICATE---------**.

But it is generated by openssl. So what is wrong?

Comment: `certificate = PEM_read_PUBKEY` is incorrect. For the verify part, see [How to use X509_verify()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16475549/608639).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused between a RSA Public Key and a x509 certificate.  The x509 certificate can contain a RSA Public Key, but the "public key" by itself (formatted in PEM format) is what PEM_read_PUBKEY reads in.  You have a x509 certificate so you want to use something like [PEM_read_X509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_read_X509.html) to read in the x509 certificate and then use [X509_get_pubkey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/X509_get_pubkey.html) to extract the public key from the X509 certificate.

Comment: However, I am not able to verify the signature. Could you please look to 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846989/how-to-verify-private-rsa-signed-signature-with-corresponding-x509-certificate 

 maybe?